# Random IOException in StreamReader

Tags: c#, .net, instagram, instagram-api, streamreader

I have the following helper method to execute and retrieve JSON out of a `HttpWebRequest`.

The requests in question are being made to the Instagram API (media/tag endpoint). The method should take a request and very simply return the JSON.

```
private static string RequestToJson(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

However randomly I would receive the following exception (Visual Studio highlights the ReadToEnd() as the cause):

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in 
System.dll

Additional information: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Dozens of request are made , with the exception appearing randomly. 
Does anyone know what might cause this?

Notes:

Every request is being made on a new thread. 

The stream.CanRead property is set to false only when the exception occurs.